# Laravel 6.2 app on heroku; routes not working

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-6.2

I have successfully deployed a laravel 6.2 app on heroku and it working fine, until i try to access any other routes other than main landing page.

My log (Snipped for readability):

> 2020-01-04T04:54:17.512849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/service" host=ridgearchitectsandengineers.herokuapp.com request_id=261880df-693e-4dda-85e5-5a20720a21fd fwd="110.44.124.147" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=691 protocol=https
>   2020-01-04T04:54:17.513095+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020/01/04 04:54:17 [error] 145#0: *131 open() "/app/public/service" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.81.170.215, server: localhost, request: "GET /service HTTP/1.1", host: "ridgearchitectsandengineers.herokuapp.com", referrer: "https://ridgearchitectsandengineers.herokuapp.com/"
>   2020-01-04T04:54:17.516131+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.81.170.215 - - [04/Jan/2020:04:54:17 +0000] "GET /service HTTP/1.1" 404 548 "https://ridgearchitectsandengineers.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36

The routes are working fine in my local machine though.
I am putting my Procfile as well if it is relevant:

> web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx public/

My .htaccess :

> Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Couple of things:
- you don't need .htaccess file - it does not work with nginx
- even if you do use apache as server there  is no need for .htaccess 
- can you try different build for heroku, heroku docs suggesting apache build - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel#creating-a-procfile

Comment: My htaccess always routing to index page, however my routing is not working

Comment: @sijan Any chance

Answer (score 1):

it might be late, but have you tried change the Procfile using apache2 instead of nginx? If it's running, it could be that you need to add an additional nginx configuration file and edit the Procfile so that the web engine will use your custom nginx config in case that you still want to use nginx as your web engine.

based on the example that Heroku gave, the nginx.conf file would be like this:

```
location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    # rewrite all to index.php
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
    # ensure that /index.php isn't accessible directly, but only through a rewrite
    internal;
}
```

and the Procfile would be like this:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf public/
```

you can see more information at [this site](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#nginx).